# Controller HABTM variables not loading in view

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I have two related models in a HasAndBelongsToMany association: Subcategoria has many Paquetes, Paquete has many Subcategorias.

In my subcategory page I need to load the related paquetes, and according to my debug-kit toolbar the variables are being loaded correctly. The problem is the view is showing me an "undefined property" error code. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't quite get what's the problem.

My models:

```
class SubcategoriasTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('subcategorias');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Categorias', [
            'foreignKey' => 'categoria_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Paquetes');
    }
}

class PaquetesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('paquetes');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsToMany('Subcategorias', [
            'foreignKey' => 'paquete_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'subcategoria_id',
            'joinTable' => 'paquetes_subcategorias',
        'dependant' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

The controller I'm having troubles with:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

class SubcategoriasController extends AppController
{

    public function content($slug = null)
    {
    $subcategory = $this->Subcategorias
            ->findBySlug($slug)
            ->select(['title', 'id'])
            ->contain('Paquetes', function (Query $q) {
                return $q
                    ->select(['name', 'slug','cost','currency'])
                    ->where(['Paquetes.status' => true]);
            });

    $this->set(compact('subcategory',$subcategory));
    }
}
```

The corresponging view template (content.ctp):

```
<?php
    $subcategoryName = $subcategory->title;
    $title = $subcategoryName;
    $this->assign('title', $title); 
?>

<h1><?= $title ?></h1>
<?php foreach($subcategory->paquetes as $paquete) : ?>
    <!-- Each Paquete's loaded fields. -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So far I'm getting the following error message:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$title [APP/Template\Subcategorias\content.ctp, line 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `first()` or `firstOrFail()` on the query you built, so in your view `$subcategory` is still just a Query object, not an Entity.

You probably meant:

```
$subcategory = $this->Subcategorias
    ->findBySlug($slug)
    ->select(['title', 'id'])
    ->contain('Paquetes', function (Query $q) {
        return $q
            ->select(['name', 'slug','cost','currency'])
            ->where(['Paquetes.status' => true]);
    })
->firstOrFail(); // This is the line that fetches the result and marshals it into an Subcategorias Entity
```

Comment: I had tried adding the line before, but I hadn't realized the order mattered (and it kept throwing me a "Call to undefined method" error notice). It works now! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah most of those functions return the Query object so you can chain them, and order doesnt frequently matter, some might override others so keep that in mind. But at the end either call first/firstOrFail/toArray, or iterate over it with foreach, and it'll finally run the query and output results.